# Spaces in a batch file throwing errors in SQL

Tags: sql-server, csv, batch-file

I'm trying to read a file using a batch file and then joining the data I retrieve with an SQL command in that same batch file.  When my paths do not contain spaces it works very well.  However, when I use paths that have spaces I get an SQL error in return.

CODE:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ("N:\Mica Projects\Lab Reports\acct%mydate%.csv") DO call :concat %%i
SET acct=%acct:~0,-1%
bcp "SELECT aVIS.AccountNumber, aVIS.VisitID, aVIS.Name, aVIS.LocationID, aVIS.InpatientOrOutpatient , oORD.OrderDateTime, oORD.OrderNumber, oORD.OrderedProcedure, oORD.OrderedProcedureMnemonic, oORD.OrderedProcedureName, oORD.EnteredUserID , oORD.ServiceDateTime FROM [boringmdb].[dbo].[OeOrders] oORD JOIN [boringmdb].[dbo].[AdmVisits] aVIS ON oORD.VisitID = aVIS.VisitID WHERE oORD.VisitID in (SELECT DISTINCT(VisitID) FROM [boringmdb].[dbo].[AdmVisits] WHERE AccountNumber IN (%acct%)) AND oORD.Category IN ('BBK','LAB','MIC','OVBBK','OVLAB','OVMIC','OVPTH','PTH') ORDER BY aVIS.AccountNumber" queryout "N:\Mica Projects\Lab Reports\Result_Data%mydate%.csv" -c -t, -S MICA-01 -T
ECHO %acct
```

When I run the above I get this:

```
SQLState = 3700, NativeError = 105
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server] Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' 'N:\MICA')) AND oORD.Category IN ('BBK','LAB','MIC','OVBBK','OVLAB','OVMIC','OVPTH','PTH') ORDER BY aVIS.AccountNumber'.
SQLState = 3700, NativeError = 102
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ' 'N:\MICA')) AND oORD.Category IN ('BBK','LAB','MIC','OVBBK','OVLAB','OVMIC','OVPTH','PTH') ORDER BY aVIS.AccountNumber'.
SQLState = 3700, NativeError = 8180
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

I am most likely missing the obvious.  Can anyone help with this please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the first line should have... DO CALL :concat "%%~i"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("N:\Mica Projects\Lab Reports\acct%mydate%.csv") DO call :concat "%%~i"
```

Without the `usebackq` option double-quoted strings (`""`) are considered as literal strings rather than file paths by `for /F`.

I also changed the `call` parameter for it to be always double-quoted (the `~` modifier removes quotes if present).

Comment: Thank you Aschipfl.  I greatly appreciate your solution and it works perfectly.